# Why my laptop goes to sleep mode automatically even if all the power settings are fine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, automation, power-management

I have a strange problem in my laptop that why it goes to sleep automatically even if all power settings are fine?

I am using Windows 10 Home 64-bit by the way.

Kindly share your thoughts!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

So I would check that the active power setting you have chosen actually is set to never go to sleep. There are 3 settings and it might be that the High Performance, Balanced or Power Saver settings were changed to never sleep but not selected or applied.

The other thing I would check is the BIOS setup. You may have power settings there that the OS is not controlling.